# Deploy a monolithic and Microservices in same Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-container

Can I deploy both an asp.net Monolithic application and a Microservices application in the Same Docker Container? How to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this is not advisable, the better way is deploying two docker containers and possibly sharing a network (or other resources) between them

However, it's still possible to achieve by using one of two ways:

1. Make an entry point to be a script that starts all the required processes in one container.
2. Use tools like supervisord

A much more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).